# How to Make Gtk3 Applications Look Better On Ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk

I Just began Gtk3 development with natty and for my first app , the Interface looks horrible.
It's like that of windows 98 O.o ! 
A screenshot to show you what i mean >> http://www.dumpyourphoto.com/photo/view/69642/2pnZdX
I\m using the sample code from getting started with gtk.

Comment: Can you add a few more widgets, i can't say if it looks ugly with just one button. 

But you should know that Gtk3 is new. It was released March 2011, it will need 2 years until be stable und have lots of good themes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a programming issue, it's a system configuration issue. You need to install a GTK3 theme.

(For best results, I'd advise installing a theme package that comprises a GTK2 **and** GTK3 theme, like Adwance. Otherwise your GTK2 apps will look poor instead.)

Comment: But any instructions on how to install it will be really nice

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 Classic Gnome Desktop (No Unity)

Comment: You need the "gnome-themes-standard" package installed (that's in Debian, I don't know whether it's called the same in Ubuntu). You'll need to (a) [download Adwance](http://thedeviantmars.deviantart.com/art/Adwance-gtk3-207704533), (b) extract the "Adwance" folder, (c) (b) open up *Preferences » Appearance* and drag this folder into the "Theme" area. You can delete the downloaded stuff after you do all this.

Answer (score 0):

Report a bug/wish to Gnome3 and Ubuntu that their default Gtk theme looks horrible?